# How to make a dictionary, in which multiple values access one value(Python)

Tags: python, dictionary, key, multiple-value

I want to make a Python dictionary. I want values like 0.25, 0.30, 0.35 to be keys in this dictionary. The problems is that I have values like 0.264, 0.313, 0.367. I want this values to access the keys e.g. I want every value from 0.25(inclusive) to 0.30(exclusive) to access the value under the key 0.25. Any ideas how to do this? I think I've done that before somehow, but I have no ideas right now.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you are looking for a way to round float values down to the nearest multiple of `0.05`?

Comment: Yes, that would be ok too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a subclass of `dict` with adjusted `__getitem__`, `__setitem__`, `__delitem__`, `__contains__`, `get()`, `pop()` and `update()` methods that round the key:

```
class RoundingDict(dict):
    def _round(self, key):
        return int(key * 20) / 20.0

    def __contains__(self, key):
        return super(RoundingDict, self).__contains__(self._round(key))

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return super(RoundingDict, self).__getitem__(self._round(key))

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        super(RoundingDict, self).__setitem__(self._round(key), value)

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        super(RoundingDict, self).__delitem__(self._round(key))

    def get(self, key, default=None):
        return super(RoundingDict, self).get(self._round(key), default)

    def pop(self, key, default=None):
        return super(RoundingDict, self).pop(self._round(key), default)

    def update(self, iterable):
        try:
            super(RoundingDict, self).update({
                self._round(k): v for k, v in iterable.iteritems()})
        except AttributeError:
            super(RoundingDict, self).update((
                (self._round(k), v) for k, v in iterable))
```

This floors any key down to the nearest `0.05` multiple when getting, setting or deleting individual keys, as well as when updating the dictionary with multiple keys:

```
>>> d = RoundingDict()
>>> d[0.346] = 'Foo'
>>> d[0.34]
'Foo'
>>> d[0.30]
'Foo'
>>> d[0.35]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 6, in __getitem__
KeyError: 0.35
>>> d.get(0.34)
'Foo'
>>> d.get(0.35, 'default')
'default'
```

Comment: If you only want to handle missing keys when calling `get`, one can just define a `__missing__` method instead.

Comment: @SteinarLima: using `__missing__` is very different from calling `.get()`.

Comment: If I read the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) correctly, `__missing__` will be called (if defined) when the key is not present.

Comment: @SteinarLima `get` is more similar to: `if key in dict: return dict[key]` - thus avoids the `__getitem__` call that'd trigger the `__missing__`...

Comment: @SteinarLima: `__missing__` will only be called when calling `__getitem__` with a key not yet present. `get()` does gives you the option to *not* alter the dictionary when looking for a default. The usecases are very distinct.

Comment: @SteinarLima: In fact `dict.get()` **never** alters the dictionary, even when `__missing__` is set. The `default` value is always returned for missing keys (which defaults to `None`).

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to make a custom dictionary class where the `__getitem__` method rounds down the value before calling the standard `__getitem__` method.

Comment: Indeed!  That's what happens when you answer of the top of your head about something you've never tried.